# Laravel 4.2 mail send, redirect with flash data issue

Tags: laravel-4

I'm trying to create a simple contact form but unfortunately having some trouble getting the flash data to show once redirected.

```
    Mail::send('emails.contact', $data, function($message) {
        $message->to('support@domain.com', Input::get('name'))
            ->subject('Contact Form');
    });

    Mail::send('emails.received', $data, function($message) {
        $message->to(Input::get('email'), 'Website Owner')
            ->subject('Message received');
    });

    return Redirect::to('contact')->with('messages', 'Thank you, your message has been received');
```

When form is submitted, it successfully sends two emails. One to the website admin, the other to the person who submitted the form.

Problem being, once redirected I expect to see the flash data which I don't. I am currently using var_dump(Session::all()) to show data.

Saying this, when I remove one or both Mail functions, the flash data displays correct on submit.

Furthermore, the above script is working on a local build but not on my development server.

I am very stuck and have been looking for a solution for a few hours, any insight will be much appreciated!